# Login prompt for xlsx document from SharePoint site in IE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint site with anonymous access where I have an Excel file along with other PDF files. The issue is whenever I try to open the Excel file in IE it asks for Open Save and Save As...I select Open and then It asks for credential again. I click Cancel without entering my credential and the excel file opens without any issue. I came across this forum and tried everything mentioned here but no luck. Does any one faced similar issue. Please help!!

Forum I followed: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/45feb132-c304-4521-8b79-42236a829aab/login-prompt-appearing-when-opening-office-documents?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Environment: SharePoint 2007
Window 7
Office 2007

Comment: Does the same thing happen to anonymous users or users will only read permissions?

Comment: It happens with everyone